# Is it possible to use these icons (http://map-icons.com/) on Leaflet.js?

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I used this icons on a Google Maps in some many projects, but i want to use them on Leaflet map. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the docs.

https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.3.0.html#marker-icon

The docs suggest that you can pass an "icon" option for your marker.

https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.3.0.html#icon

The docs also shows an example on how to create your own marker icon. "iconUrl" should be what you're looking for.